# How to changes all css values at once that are set to rem based on 14px base size as new base size is 10px

Tags: css, font-size

I have a css file with 14px base size for rem. I want to make base size 10px and then change all css values according to that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
:root {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

By default, 1 rem is equal to 14px I think.
Now, 1rem is equal to 10px.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

and also can use

```
:root{
  font-size: 10px;
}
```